# How to get all child list from Firebase Android by simple for loop

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below code has given me all child in Firebase by a forEach loop:

```
final Query query = mDataBaseReference_info_channels.child(getUserDetails().getUserId()).child("channels");

query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
DebugLog.d("\n test: " + dsp.toString());
}
}
```

But I want to use for loop and get the last position and fire an again query. I don't want use like this below code:

```
i=0;
for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        i++;
if(i==datasnapt.getchildren)
{
   //fire a api 
}
}
```

Anyone have solution then please give me answer.

Comment: do you want only last row from **channels** node ?

Comment: thanks @NiravBhavasr but i need last position only so i fired a api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the last position from a `DataSnapshot` object you can count the children using the following line of code:

```
long count = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
```

And your last item will be at position:

```
int lastPosition = (int) count - 1;
```

If you want to use a for loop, then please use the following code:

```
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<YourClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            YourClass yourClass = ds.getValue(YourClass.class);
            list.add(yourClass);
        }

        YourClass lastItem = list.get(list.size() - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

In this way you can get the item from the last postion or from any other position. I have used `YourClass` as an example. Your `YourClass` could be the String class or any other model class.

Comment: thanks @AlexMamo you got it 
your answer is not proper for my solution but you give me a hint 
thank you

Answer (score 2):

Because `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` return `Iterable<DataSnapshot>` . use Iterator to get last item from collection :

```
DataSnapshot lastDataSnapshot = null;
Iterable<DataSnapshot>  iterable= dataSnapshot.getChildren();
for (Iterator iterator = iterable.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
  lastDataSnapshot = iterator.next();
}
```

`lastDataSnapshot` is last item from DataSnapshot . use it to fire next api.

Comment: thanks, buddy, but i need last position so he reach last position then i fired it

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, if you want to get only last row of **Channel** node from your database.

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = Firebase.getInstance().getReference();


databaseReference.child(getUserDetails().getUserId()).child("channels").orderByKey().limitToLast(1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // here dataSnapshot is the value of last position.

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        //Handle possible errors.
    }
});
```